# Problem with Apscheduler and Qtimer in Pyqt5 Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, thread-safety, apscheduler

I am using PYQT5 and APScheduler lib to handle some functions: turn on, off camera at specific time.
This is error i got:

```
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
```

My camera stopped but not start and I am not sure how to fix them. Pls help me

- MainWindow:

  ````
  class MainWindow(QWidget):
      # class constructor
      def __init__(self):
          # call QWidget constructor
          super().__init__()
          self.ui = Ui_Form()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)

          # create a timer
          self.timer = QTimer()

          self.sch = Scheduler()
          self.sch.add(self.start_webcam)
          self.sch.start()
      def start_webcam(self):

          # # set timer timeout callback function
          self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
          self.timer.start(5)
    ```
  ````
- Schedule:

  ```
  class Scheduler(QtCore.QObject):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.sched = QtScheduler()

     def add(self, job_function):

         trigger_on = CronTrigger(
             year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="10", minute="53", second="0"
         )
         self.sched.add_job(job_function, trigger=trigger_on,)
     def start(self):
         self.sched.start()
  ```

Comment: The error says what the [documentation also explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details): "you must start and stop the timer in its thread; it is not possible to start a timer from another thread." I'm not familiar with aps, but I'd start by creating the timer inside `start_webcam()` instead of doing it in `__init__`.

Comment: i tried but still same errors